# How to group several lines in a file

Tags: shell-script

For example I have a file like this:

```
group1
data1
data2
data3
group2
data1
data2
data3
group3
data1
data2
data3
```

I want to get specific group in the file and its data. For example, just want to get all the data under `group2` only.

Comment: If there are always be 3 lines present after pattern then you can use `grep -A 3 group2 filename`

Comment: see also [How to select lines between two patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$0=="group2" {print; gr=1; next}; /^group/ {gr=0}; gr {print}' file.txt
```

- `$0=="group2" {print; gr=1; next}`, if the line contains only `group2`, we print the line, set variable `gr` to 1 (true) and go to the next line
- `/^group/ {gr=0}`, if line starts with `group` (any other group), we set `gr` to 0 (false)
- `gr {print}` prints the line when `gr` is true. As the default action of `awk` is to print the line (record), you can do:

  ```
  awk '$0=="group2" {print; gr=1; next}; /^group/ {gr=0}; gr' file.txt
  ```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
group1
data1
data2
data3
group2
data1
data2
data3
data4
group3
data1
data2
data3

$ awk '$0=="group2" {print; gr=1; next}; /^group/ {gr=0}; gr {print}' file.txt 
group2
data1
data2
data3
data4
```